# Google Chrome Randomly Displaying Certain Webpages' text in italics

Tags: google-chrome

randomly today, Chrome has started displaying certain webpages only in italic fonts - this includes WhatsApp Web, Youtube, Twitter - most websites are ok, but these are the problematic ones I've found so far.

Bit clueless, had a search around the Internet, but most threads are dated, so not sure where to begin!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Best guess right now is the ongoing DDoS attacks against Dyn.

Current refs [probably out of date by tomorrow]

https://www.dynstatus.com/incidents/nlr4yrr162t8

> - **Update**
>     This DDoS attack may also be impacting Dyn Managed DNS advanced services with possible delays in monitoring. Our Engineers
>     are continuing to work on mitigating this issue.
>     <sup>Posted 24 minutes
>     ago. Oct 21, 2016 - 16:48 UTC</sup>
> - **Investigating**
>     As of 15:52 UTC, we have begun monitoring and mitigating a DDoS attack against our Dyn Managed DNS infrastructure.
>     Our Engineers are continuing to work on mitigating this issue.
>     <sup>Posted
>     about 1 hour ago. Oct 21, 2016 - 16:06 UTC</sup>

https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasneemnashrulla/denial-of-service-attack-dyn?utm_term=.oaLzza5axL#.thQqq9d9kb

> **A Major Denial Of Service Attack Brought Down Websites On The US East Coast**
>   After Dyn said it weathered the first attack, it reported another hours later.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have been following that - still no changes though, is it likely to still be like this?

Comment: Possibly. Your router might still be full of stale info. Power-cycle it & all other network hardware, then puter last & give it another go.

Comment: Welcome - let me know how it goes :)

Comment: OK, done what you suggested, however now I can't access Facebook or WhatsApp - every other website is fine. You reckon this is still from the DDoD stuff? Thanks!

Comment: Update - FB and WhatSapp now working, however the italizied text issue is still here :(

Comment: Might be cached wrongly. I don't use Chrome so idk where to look to fix that. Maybe test a different browser.